# Fast check if strings contain specific words

Tags: php, string, search, find, compare

I have a bunch of strings in database, on which i'm hoping to use some kind of data structure, instead of doing an SQL "WHERE 'a b' LIKE 'a%'" kind of search.

(In real world example these can be up to 5000)
A - Let's say i have the words/needles: `for, in, like, release`
Note: these are always the same, the only thing that can happen here is to expand, but they don't change

(In real world example these can be up to 50)
B - Then i have the other words/haystacks: `for people, in magazine, date of release, daily news`
Note: These are dynamic, they are always different

I'd like to know of a good way to find/remove all the words from B, which start or end in any of the words from A

So the ones i would remove from the example, would be: `for people, in magazine, date of release`

I'm happy even with a generic idea, which i can implement in PHP

PS: I might go back to mysql if all the given ideas are slower, then using a mysql LIKE search, so i'd prefer something faster, or at least as fast as mysql

Answer (score 0):

One solution i could think of would be to split the words from B
`for, people, in, magazine, date, of, release`

Mark those that exist in A
`for, in, release`

This way we would end up with much smaller data and it would be fine to just do an strpos on them in a foreach loop

Let me know if you know of a better way.